# Removing a switch-case in a function called from a loop

Tags: c, optimization, switch-statement, function-pointers

I have a function called `blend_pixels()` whose task is to blend a single pixel onto another pixel according to the specified blending mode. That function is in turn called by pretty much any function that wants to draw anything.

The problem is that function is called for every single pixel, that means it's called tens of millions of times a second, and it contains a switch-case statement going through all possible blending modes until it finds the right one.

Obviously this is somewhat slower than calling a function that directly does the desired operations, and that's the problem I'm trying to fix. The parent functions that call `blend_pixels()` usually just pass on the blending mode that they themselves received as an argument once called, so I can't just have them called a small function that would only do one blending mode. But the choice only needs to be done once for every call of the parent function (the parent functions operate on a lot of pixels per call whereas `blend_pixels()` is called for every single pixel, in a loop going through all the necessary pixels).

The function looks like this:

```
void blend_pixels(lrgb_t *bg, lrgb_t fg, int32_t p, const int mode)
{
    int32_t r, g, b;

    switch (mode)
    {
        case SOLID:
            *bg = fg;
            break;

        case ADD:
            r = (fg.r * p >> 15) + bg->r;   if (r>ONE) bg->r = ONE; else bg->r = r;
            g = (fg.g * p >> 15) + bg->g;   if (g>ONE) bg->g = ONE; else bg->g = g;
            b = (fg.b * p >> 15) + bg->b;   if (b>ONE) bg->b = ONE; else bg->b = b;
            break;

        case SUB:
            r = -(fg.r * p >> 15) + bg->r;  if (r<0) bg->r = 0; else bg->r = r;
            g = -(fg.g * p >> 15) + bg->g;  if (g<0) bg->g = 0; else bg->g = g;
            b = -(fg.b * p >> 15) + bg->b;  if (b<0) bg->b = 0; else bg->b = b;
            break;

        case MUL:
            ... // you get the idea
    }
}
```

and is called in this kind of way:

```
void parent_function(lrgb_t *fb, int w, int h, lrgb_t colour, ... int blendingmode)
{
    ...
    for (iy=y0; iy<y1; iy++)
        for (ix=x0; ix<x1; ix++)
        {
            p = some_weighting_formula();

            blend_pixels(&fb[iy*w+ix], colour, p, blendingmode);
        }
}
```

which itself might be called like:

```
parent_function(fb, w, h, orange, ... /*whatever*/, ADD);
```

"ADD" being an integer from an enum

So clearly any switch-case to pick the blending algorithm should be done outside of `parent_function`'s loops. But how?

Comment: Use a function pointer to blend. However, did you benchmark properly? how much slower is the switch actually? Don't start premature optimisations. That does not remove the need to carefully design your interface, though.

Comment: I expect a switch statement to be very fast.  As in not at all slower.  The statement that "switch-case statement going through all possible blending modes until it finds the right one" is not generally how the code behind a switch statement works.  It is normally implemented as a jump table allowing a direct jump to the correct logic.

Comment: I did benchmark carefully, the difference in overall performance is over 10%. So I'd say the switch statement is quite fast, but done tens of millions of times a second it's slower than no switch statement at all! I'd say it probably takes a cycle or two everytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with function pointers.

First define a typedef for your function pointer:

```
typedef void (*blend_function)(lrgb_t *, lrgb_t, int32_t);
```

Then break out each part of `blend_pixels` into its own function, each with identical parameters and return type as the typedef:

```
void blend_pixels_add(lrgb_t *bg, lrgb_t fg, int32_t p)
...
void blend_pixels_sub(lrgb_t *bg, lrgb_t fg, int32_t p)
...
void blend_pixels_mult(lrgb_t *bg, lrgb_t fg, int32_t p)
...
```

Then in your parent function, you can assign a variable of the function pointer type, and assign it the address of the function you want to use:

```
void parent_function(lrgb_t *fb, int w, int h, lrgb_t colour, ... int blendingmode)
{
    ...
    blend_function blend;
    switch (blendingmode)
    {
        case ADD:
            blend = blend_pixels_add;
            break;
        case SUB:
            blend = blend_pixels_sub;
            break;
        ...
    }
    for (iy=y0; iy<y1; iy++)
        for (ix=x0; ix<x1; ix++)
        {
            p = some_weighting_formula();

            blend(&fb[iy*w+ix], colour, p);
        }
}
```

Comment: To add to dbush's answer: if there's more than one "parent function", you'd want to move the `switch(blendingmode)` block into a common function so you could do `blend_function blend = get_blend_function( blendingmode );` in each parent.  BUT, as others have commented, check that the `switch` in the original form is really a source of delay before making a wholesale change to your code.

Comment: Interesting, thank you! Just wondering though, will there be a difference in performance between using a function pointer like this and using a hardcoded function? The hardcoded function would probably get inlined, but would the function pointed to by the pointer get inlined as well? Yes I checked it's a source of delay by commenting out the switch and leaving only ADD's code, the difference is well over 10%.

Comment: @MichelRouzic The function call can't be inlined because the function to call is determined at runtime.  As for the performance of the function call, benchmark it and see how it works.

Comment: I just implemented it, with a function pointer is faster but still not quite as fast as hardcoding (removing the switch statement to only have the ADD code left). 2.73 FPS with switch, 3.09 hardcoded and 3.00 with a function pointer.

Comment: Wait I think the discrepancy might be due to a maddening quirk in benchmarking. When I hardcode a call to blend_add() it's no faster than using a pointer to it, however when I hardcode a call to the edited blend_pixels() with the switch statement commented it the latter is faster by a few percent, consistently so no matter how many times I build and test one way then the other way. Even though they're identical. So it probably means nothing.

Comment: By the way I figured that instead of having a function that turns an integer (e.g. ADD) into a function pointer I should just directly pass the function pointer, and since it's usually hardcoded as in I call `parent_function(fb, w, h, orange, blend_add);` instead of `parent_function(fb, w, h, orange, ADD);` maybe that allows it to get inlined?

Answer (score 0):

Addressing your concern that "and it contains a switch-case statement going through all possible blending modes until it finds the right one.", this is probably not what really happens.

Switch statements are generally compiled into what is called a jump table.  In a jump table, the code does not step through all of the cases looking for the correct one, instead the argument of the switch() statement is used as the index in an array of addresses.  Something like:

```
jump_table[SOLID] -> case SOLID address
jump_table[ADD] -> case ADD address
...
```

So, in this sort of implementation, a switch statement that is considering many, many values should be just as fast as a hand-coded function pointer solution because that is essentially what the compiler builds.